# Pandas combining information from several columns where value depends on values in the same row

Tags: pandas, apply

I am trying to compress information from several columns in to one.  The data frame has a 'step',  'tx' and an 'rx' column.  These are followed by columns that show the accumulated value transmitted between parties so "A_to_B", etc.  But I want to compress the information to a single column that shows the appropriate accumulated value at a given step for a given transmission. So value in the combined column depends on what parties are involved in the transmission ie. the value depends on other values in the same row.  The code below does that:

```
u = pd.DataFrame()
u["step"] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
u["tx"] = pd.Series(["A","A","A","A","A","B"])
u["rx"] = pd.Series(["B","C","B","C","C","A"])
u["A_to_B"] = pd.Series([15,15,30,30,30,30])
u["A_to_C"] = pd.Series([0,20,20,40,50,50])
u["B_to_A"] = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,100])

print(u)

def compact(x):
  rx = x["rx"]
  tx = x["tx"]
  x["combo"] = x[tx + "_to_" + rx]
  return x

u = u.apply(lambda x: compact(x), axis=1)

print(u)
```

It yields the following:

```
   step tx rx  A_to_B  A_to_C  B_to_A
0     1  A  B      15       0       0
1     2  A  C      15      20       0
2     3  A  B      30      20       0
3     4  A  C      30      40       0
4     5  A  C      30      50       0
5     6  B  A      30      50     100
   step tx rx  A_to_B  A_to_C  B_to_A  combo
0     1  A  B      15       0       0     15
1     2  A  C      15      20       0     20
2     3  A  B      30      20       0     30
3     4  A  C      30      40       0     40
4     5  A  C      30      50       0     50
5     6  B  A      30      50     100    100
```

The problem is that this is *very* slow to run on a lot of rows.  Is there a more efficient/effective way to do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) here:

```
s=u['tx']+'_to_'+u['rx']
u['combo']=u.lookup(s.index,s)
```

Same thing using a function(if you need):

```
def compact(x):
    s=x['tx']+'_to_'+x['rx']
    return x.assign(combo=x.lookup(s.index,s))
compact(u)
```

---

```
   step tx rx  A_to_B  A_to_C  B_to_A  combo
0     1  A  B      15       0       0     15
1     2  A  C      15      20       0     20
2     3  A  B      30      20       0     30
3     4  A  C      30      40       0     40
4     5  A  C      30      50       0     50
5     6  B  A      30      50     100    100
```

---

Performance:

```
u = pd.concat([u]*2000,ignore_index=True)
%%timeit
s=u['tx']+'_to_'+u['rx']
u.lookup(s.index,s)
#16.6 ms ± 754 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit
u.assign(lookup=u['tx'].str.cat(u['rx'], sep='_to_')).apply(lambda x: x[x['lookup']],1)
#613 ms ± 79.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#lookup is faster than apply
```

Comment: This is significantly faster! On my real data set it's 17 sec on 1.1 million rows, 40 sec on 3.3 million rows, and about 5 min on 21 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `assign` and create the lookup column. Then with `apply` fetch values.

```
u['combo'] = u.assign(lookup=u['tx'].str.cat(u['rx'], sep='_to_')).apply(lambda x: x[x['lookup']],1)
```

Output:

```
   step tx rx  A_to_B  A_to_C  B_to_A  combo
0     1  A  B      15       0       0     15
1     2  A  C      15      20       0     20
2     3  A  B      30      20       0     30
3     4  A  C      30      40       0     40
4     5  A  C      30      50       0     50
5     6  B  A      30      50     100    100
```